# Vue.js How to set scroll position back to top?

Tags: vue.js, scrollview

So whenever I click the "edit" button, a dialog pops up with a scrollbar where I can fill out information. But when I click "cancel" or "save" and then click that same "edit" button, the dialog pops up at the same scroll position. I would like to, every time when I click "edit" and the dialog opens up, be always at the top of the dialog page not where I left off last.

```html
<template>
    <!-- <div class="text-xs-center" v-if="storeState.admin" lazy> --> 
      <v-dialog 
      transition="dialog-bottom-transition" 
      scrollable 
      fullscreen 
      v-model="sheet" 
      v-if="storeState.admin"  
      lazy 
      persistent 
    > 
      <template v-slot:activator="{on}"> 
        <v-btn flat color="green" dark icon v-on="on"> 
            <v-icon>edit</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </template>
        <div background-color="transparent" style="margin: auto auto 0 auto"> 
          <v-card px-5 max-width="800px"> 
            <v-card-title>
                ADD SCHOLARSHIP
            </v-card-title>

        <v-form v-model="addDisabled" validation ref="editForm">
            <v-container>
            <v-layout wrap>
                <v-flex
                xs12
                md4
                >
                <v-text-field
                    v-model="scholarship.title"
                    label="Scholarship name"
                    :counter="maxLength"
                    :rules="[maxLength_rules.max, minLength_rules.min]"
                    required
                ></v-text-field>
                </v-flex>

                <v-flex xs12 md4>
                <v-text-field
                    v-model="scholarship.faculty"
                    label="Faculty"
                    :counter="maxLength"
                    :rules="[maxLength_rules.max, minLength_rules.min]"
                    required
                ></v-text-field>
                </v-flex>

                <v-flex xs12 md4>
                <v-text-field
                    v-model="scholarship.dollarAmount"
                    label="Award amount"
                    required
                    :rules="[amount_rules.range, minLength_rules.min]"
                ></v-text-field>
                </v-flex>

           <v-flex ml-2 xs12 sm6 md4>
            <v-menu
              ref="menu2"
              v-model="menu2"
              :close-on-content-click="false"
              :nudge-right="40"
              :return-value.sync="availableDate"
              transition="scale-transition"
              offset-y
              full-width
              min-width="290px"
            >
              <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                <v-text-field
                  v-model="scholarship.available"
                  label="Date Available"
                  prepend-icon="event"
                  :rules="[minLength_rules.min]"
                  readonly
                  v-on="on"
                ></v-text-field>
              </template>
              <v-date-picker v-model="availableDate" no-title scrollable>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="menu2 = false">Cancel</v-btn>
                <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="$refs.menu2.save(availableDate)">OK</v-btn>
              </v-date-picker>
            </v-menu>
          </v-flex>


          <v-flex ml-2 xs12 sm6 md4>
            <v-menu
              ref="menu1"
              v-model="menu1"
              :close-on-content-click="false"
              :nudge-right="40"
              :return-value.sync="dueDate"

              transition="scale-transition"
              offset-y
              full-width
              min-width="290px"
            >
              <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                <v-text-field
                  v-model="scholarship.deadline"
                  label="Due Date"
                  prepend-icon="event"
                  readonly
                  :rules="[minLength_rules.min]"
                  v-on="on"
                ></v-text-field>
              </template>
              <v-date-picker v-model="dueDate" no-title scrollable>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="menu1 = false">Cancel</v-btn>
                <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="$refs.menu1.save(dueDate)">OK</v-btn>
              </v-date-picker>
            </v-menu>
          </v-flex>

          <v-flex xs12 md1>
                <v-text-field
                    v-model="scholarship.requiredGpa"
                    label="Min GPA"
                    required
                    :rules="[gpa_rules.range, minLength_rules.min]"
                ></v-text-field>
                </v-flex>

                <v-flex xs12>
                    <v-textarea
                    outline
                    height="400"
                    v-model = "scholarship.description"
                    label="Scholarship Description"
                    :rules="[minLength_rules.min]"
                    ></v-textarea>
                </v-flex>


            </v-layout>
            </v-container>
        </v-form>

        <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
             <v-btn  flat @click="sheet = false" >cancel</v-btn>
            <v-btn color="primary" @click="updateFields(scholarship)"   :disabled="!addDisabled" flat >SAVE</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>

        </v-card>

  </div>
    </v-dialog>
    <!-- </div> -->
</template>


<script>
import { store } from "../store.js";
import EDITSCHOLARSHIP from '../graphql/updateScholarship.gql'


  export default {
    data: () => ({
       sheet: false,
      valid: false,
      dueDate: '',
      availableDate: '',
      storeState: store.state,
      addDisabled: true,
      menu1: '',
      menu2: '',
      gpa: '',
      title: '',
      faculty: '',
      amount: '',
      maxLength: 255,
      description: '',
      gpa_rules: {
                range: v => v <= 4.00 && v >= 0.00 && v.length <=4 || 'GPA may only be within 0.00 - 4.00',
            },
      amount_rules: {
                range: v => v <= 999999999.00 && v >= 0.00 || 'Amount must only contain numbers between 0.00 - 999999999.00',
            },
      maxLength_rules: {
         max: v => v.length <= 255|| 'Max character length is 255',
      },
      minLength_rules: {
         min: v => v.length > 0 || 'Required',
      }

    }),
    props: {
        scholarship: Object
    },
    methods: {
       validate () {
        if (this.$refs.editForm.validate()) {
          this.addDisabled = false
        }
      },
        editScholarship(scholarship) {
            if (this.$refs.editForm.validate()) {
                this.$apollo.mutate({
                    mutation: EDITSCHOLARSHIP,
                    variables: {
                      id: scholarship.id,                
                      input: {
                          available: this.availableDate,
                          deadline: this.dueDate,
                          description: this.description,
                          dollarAmount: this.amount,
                          faculty: this.faculty,
                          requiredGpa: this.gpa,
                          title: scholarship.title,
                          visible: true,
                          
                      }
                    }

                }).then( (data) => {
                    this.$emit('showSnackbar', 'Scholarship successfully updated', 'success')
                    this.sheet = false

                }).catch( (error) => {
                    this.$emit('showSnackbar', 'Scholarship update failed', 'error')
                    //this.text = error
                    //this.color = "error"
                    //this.snackbar = true
              
                })
                
            }
          },
          updateFields (scholarship) {
            this.dueDate =  scholarship.deadline
            this.availableDate = scholarship.available
            this.gpa = scholarship.requiredGpa
            this.title =  scholarship.title
            this.faculty = scholarship.faculty
            this.amount = scholarship.dollarAmount
            this.description = scholarship.description
            this.editScholarship(scholarship)
          }

    } 
  }
</script> 
 
<style> 
  .scroll { 
    overflow-y: auto; 
  } 
</style>
```

---

Answer (score 6):

This is intended behavior. If the dialog box is not removed from the DOM when closed, its previous state will be retained unless otherwise modified.

You can choose one between three approaches I can think of in hindsight, 2 of which are what you are looking for.

1. Destroy the modal when not in use and re-instantiate when opening. A simple `v-if` toggling a boolean would do the trick, or a `this.$destroy` if your dialog box is a separate vue instance.
2. Add `this.$el.scrollTop = 0` on your submit or cancel events. (A*)
3. Add `scrollWrapper.scrollTop = 0` on your open dialog box method. (B*)

---

**A**: `this.$el` on item number 2 will only work if you are scrolling in the `$el` element, otherwise, you can access the target element using `this.$el.querySelector('.scroll-wrapper')`

**B**: Same as item number 2, but this uses vanilla JS references instead of relying on Vue, you should refer to your actual scroll wrapper.

Comment: This is my teammates code that I am supposed to help with this one thing. Don't actually know anything about vue. But if I were to use 3 where do I put that?

Comment: @user7520940 Inside the method/function where you open the dialog box

Comment: The v-if option ends a transition animation if for example you are closing a dialog. Any suggestions on a way around that?

Comment: @Half_Duplex this is a 2 year old issue, so I do not have full context of the problem anymore. But I suggest writing a delay on the boolean toggle before actually toggling the boolean. something like `setTimeout(()=>{}, 500)` where the 2nd argument is the delay in ms. The delay should be enough to show the animation before toggling the final state of the boolean used in your v-if conditional

Answer (score 0):

Please add this code to the event to enable in your dialog.

```
this.$refs.editForm.$el.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})
```